# Does silence affect hero passives?

Tags: dota-2

For example - if sniper if silenced, can his (very irritating :P) headshot still proc? Or does Shadow Friend still capture souls when last hitting? Etc.

I ask because when I'm playing with an Orchid, I'm unsure as to which targets to prioritise in a teamfight i.e. if I'm against drow and sniper, should I silence drow to stop her using her silence/knock-back, or sniper to stop his mini-stun?

Hope this makes sense, let me know if not and I'll edit accordingly :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Silence will not disable passives or items. Only prevent people from actively casting a spell or interrupt a spell they are currently channelling.
EDIT: Silence will disable any passive invisibility though (Rikimaru's Ultimate, Moonlight Shadow or Broodmother in her web)

There are 2 skills in the game that WILL disable passives though. Doom's doom, and Legion Commander's duel. These are considered "mutes" and disable EVERYTHING, including items (both passives granted by the item and active item abilities). Although, Legion Commander's doesn't disable every passive in the game. So Doom is still the strongest in that regard.

As if it wasn't confusing enough another variation is Disrupter's ultimate. With the Aghs upgrade it'll disable spell casting AND item usage but NOT passives.

Here is a breakdown of it including all the inclusions and exclusions between LC and Doom's mute:
http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Silence

Comment: Wrong, if you silence riki he become visible. His inivisiblity is passive though

Comment: Rikimaru's passive is the only passive that it applies, tho.

Comment: I think your answer is too broad. Information which spells disable items is not requested in the question and therefore it is rather confusing in my opinion. Furthermore if you would want to go that road anyway you should consider adding axe's taunt as disabling items as well or any stun for that matter... . To be more precise: I would remove the Disruptor part as it goes in the wrong direction

Comment: To answer the question though: Common "silence" from either Silencer, Death Prophet, Orchid etc. only stops people from activating abilities (Passives and Items are still availible). (Riki's passive is disabled not because silences disable passives, but because riki's invisibility is off when riki is silenced, as stated on riki's ability as a special case). Doom, Disruptor and Legion have ults that are treated as something else than the average silence ("mute" as you said) and don't really fall into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Only passives invisibilities are disabled by silencing (This include Rikimaru's ultimate, Broodmother in her web and the Invisibility granted by Mirana's Moonlight Shadow).

The only way to "silence" a passive is to [Mute](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Silence#Mute) (with Doom or Duel). You can have a full list of the passives abilities disabled by Mute on the link

Comment: wizliz, whats your dota ranking? You are the first person I meet here who understands a lot of dota. (I play since beginning(wc3 roc) but with pauses)

Comment: @RayofCommand 4700 when I stoped playing a month ago to focus on the new diablo 3 extension

Comment: awesome. I played stupid in my ranking games the first 10 and ranked around 3k but my friends are all around 3700-4400. 4700 is awesome :) well done. I think my rate is around 3900. Why the hell d3 ? i played d2 for ages but d3 :/ didn't like it.